# Can Slater's condition be used for non-convex objective functions?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

As wee known, in convex optimization problem, we get strong duality if Slater's condition holds. I often use Slater condition to indicate whether an optimal solution of primary problem satisfies KKT system.

Can I use Slater's condition when the constrained inequality functions are convex, constrained equality functions are affine but the objective function is not convex?

Comment: Yes, Slater condition for convex constraints implies that KKT system is satisfied at locally optimal points. Unfortunately, I do not have a reference.

Comment: You got a quite clear answer on your Reddit post.

Answer (score 1):

See proposition 3.3.9 in the book [Nonlinear Programming](http://www.athenasc.com/nonlinbook.html) (second edition) by Dimitri Bertsekas. You will need continuous differentiability of the objective function and inequality constraints. The proof is an application of the Mangasarian-Fromovitz constraint qualification.